# Sticky header not showing on 1024 resolution?

Tags: css, wordpress, header, sticky

I have a word press site running the "The Retailer" theme. For some reason the sticky header does not appear on 1024 resolution. It works fine for any resolution above that.

Website: http://museiam.ca/

Here is my CSS for sticky header:

```
.gbtr_header_wrapper.site-header-sticky {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 25px 0;
    position: fixed;
}
.site-header-sticky {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    top: -98px;
    transition: top 0.15s ease 0s, z-index 0s ease 0.15s;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.site-header-sticky.on_page_scroll {
    top: 0;
    transition: top 0.3s ease 0s;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

Line 13822 of style.css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px)
{

    /*sticky header*/

    .site-header-sticky
    {
      display: none;
    }
```

just remove

```
.site-header-sticky
{
   display: none;
}
```

to make the sticky header continue to appear

but I would advise you against doing that because it will break the mobile styles